# jquery how to search and fulfill divs contents with object content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting stacked with inserting the content returned by an ajax call.

I have a set of divs, each div has a different id example:

```
<div id ="first_name"> content </div>
<div id ="last_name"> content </div>
<div id ="email"> content </div>
```

on the other hand I have an object with key => value example:

```
{"first_name" : "value", "last_name" : "value", "email" : "value"}
```

the keys of the object match the div's ids.

how can I on $(document).ready() search for the matching ids and object keysand put their values in jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Original answer:**

```
  for(val in entries) {
    if(entries.hasOwnProperty(val)) {
      $("#"+val).html(entries[val]);
    }
  }
```

**Edited to address question in comments:**

You want this to happen automatically? When you receive new data from an ajax call?

```
$.getJSON(url, function(entries) {
  for(val in entries) {
    if(entries.hasOwnProperty(val)) {
      $("#"+val).html(entries[val]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, works fine with some edit, i have putted it inside this function : $each(object,function(key,value){});

Comment: just another question, how this could be updated automatically

Answer (score 1):

```
for(key in myObject) {
   $('#' + key).html(object[key]);
}
```

Comment: nice answer, thanks. the same as Aesthete without the propretycheck

Answer (score 1):

You can set the content of a DIV using [.html();](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

For example:

```
$("#first_name").html('Thomas');
```

or using your object depending on how you're hydrating the JSON.

```
$("#first_name").html(yourobject.first_name);
```